# DragDrop object is null when using ui:include

Tags: java, jsf-2, drag-and-drop, richfaces

I am using drag-and-drop component in Richfaces4 and JSF2.

When I drag and drop the Action (first panel) in the target panel everything works good. But when I tried to drag and drop the Object (second panel) to the target panel. I get the following exception:

**EXCEPTION**

```
debug[16:27:48.572]: Server returned responseText: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?> <partial-response><error><error-name>class java.lang.NullPointerException</error-name><error-message><![CDATA[]]></error-message></error></partial-response>
info [16:27:48.574]: Element error
<error><error-name>class java.lang.NullPointerException</error-name><error-message><![CDATA[]]></error-message></error>
debug[16:27:48.574]: richfaces.queue: ajax submit error
debug[16:27:48.575]: richfaces.queue: Nothing to submit
error[16:27:48.576]: Received 'error@serverError' event from <div id=dropForm:list:0:j_idt42 class=rf-ind-drag ui-draggable ...>
error[16:27:48.577]: [200] class java.lang.NullPointerException:
```

**SOURCE PANELS**

```
<rich:panel id="Object">

    <h:dataTable value="#{dropBean.objects}" var="object">
        <h:column>
        <a4j:outputPanel layout="block">
             <rich:dragSource type="#{dropBean.objectType}" dragValue="#{object}" />
             <h:outputText value="#{object}"></h:outputText>
        </a4j:outputPanel>
        </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>
</rich:panel>
```

**TARGET PANEL 1**

```
<h:panelGrid columns="4">
    <rich:panel styleClass="idPanel" >
    <rich:panel>
    <rich:dropTarget acceptedTypes="ACTION" dropListener="#{dropBean.processDrop}" render="editPanel" />
    <rich:tooltip value="Drop here an Action..." />
    <a4j:outputPanel>
    <h:outputText value="#{dropBean.currentLine.action}"></h:outputText>
        </a4j:outputPanel>
    </rich:panel>
    <ui:include src="#{dropBean.pageByAction}" />
    <a4j:commandButton styleClass="opButtons" value="Add Step" action="#{dropBean.saveLine}" render="editPanel" />
</h:panelGrid>
```

The line `<ui:include src="#{dropBean.pageByAction}" />` get the correct page depending the action I have dropped in first target panel.

Here is an example of the included page(target panel 2):

**TARGET PANEL 2**

```
<h:panelGrid columns="3">
     <rich:panel styleClass="itemPanel" bodyClass="itemPanelBody">
     <rich:dropTarget acceptedTypes="OBJECT" dropListener="#{dropBean.processDrop}" render="@form" />
     <rich:tooltip value="Drop here an Object..." />
     <a4j:outputPanel>
     <h:outputText value="#{dropBean.currentLine.object}" />
     </a4j:outputPanel>
     </rich:panel>
</h:panelGrid>
```

If I remove the `<ui:include src="#{dropBean.pageByAction}" />` and insert the code directly the drop operation works correctly. But in this way, the panels are not dynamic. I need to generate the panels depending on the Action I choose.

Other things I have tried alredy and don't work:

1. Insert render="@form" "formName" "@all" trying to render all the page.
2. Change the datatable for other component like rich:list and rich:dataGrid
3. Use immediate in drop target component.

Thks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem forcing the page to refresh.

**Method in Backing bean called when I drag and drop an object into the target panel.**

```
public void processDrop(DropEvent event) {

    //process event (not relevant code)

    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    String viewId = context.getViewRoot().getViewId();
    ViewHandler handler = context.getApplication().getViewHandler();
    UIViewRoot root = handler.createView(context, viewId);
    root.setViewId(viewId);
    context.setViewRoot(root);
}
```

I am sure that this is not the **best solution** and I still ask for a better solution. Meanwhile, I will stay with it.

If anyone has a better solution, please let me know.